# SQL search with logical operators

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, search

I have a asp.net web application that needs a search page that searches for data in a specific table (SQL). Today it only has a simple LIKE query, useing parametized sql:

```
SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[1];

param[0] = new SqlParameter("@searchText", SqlDbType.VarChar);
param[0].Value = "%" + text + "%";

using (SqlDataReader dr = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(this.ConnectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "isp_Search", param))
{
       //Do something
}
```

Now I need to add the option to use logical operators to the search.

So in the textbox a user might search for things like

```
Adam OR Adams
James AND NOT Jame
Douglas AND (Adam OR Adams)
```

Adding full-text indexing to the table is not a preferred option since I do not control the data model.

I'm looking for a method of interpreting the text queries and convert into a SQL statement with the appropriate number of SqlParams.

```
searchexpression = "Douglas AND (Adam OR Adams)"
MakeSearchQuery(searchexpression, out sqlquery, out SqlParam[] params)
```

Would return somelike like

```
sqlquery = "SELECT someFields FROM table WHERE someField=@Param1 AND (someField=@Param2 OR someField=@Param3)"
```

And a sqlParams like

```
sqlParam[0] = 'Douglas'
sqlParam[1] = 'Adam'
sqlParam[2] = 'Adams'
```

Now there must be someone that have made something like this before? I've search both SO and Google without any real success. And pointers to either open source/free code or a good idea on how to convert the search expression into SQL is welcome.

Comment: Which SQL engine do you work with, the answer differs per database. some support regexp, some do not.

Answer (score 2):

The parsing of the query via and/or/() etc needs to be done via some kind of parser. For something this simple, a [shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) should do nicely (and is how we handle the and/or/not etc when filtering SE on tags, although the *full* support for bracketed sub-expressions is only available internally). This will generate a tree of the operations, i.e. (here using prefix representation, but it is more typically used to produce an AST)

```
and("Douglas", or("adam", "adams"))
```

which you then need to use to generate TSQL. Not trivial, but not rocket-science either.